# <li> cannot appear as a child of <select>

Tags: html, reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui, textfield

Getting below error while using **native** in **Select**

```
<TextField 
  select
  value={options.length ? value : defaultValue}
  SelectProps={{
    native: true,
  }}>
```

I am using material UI **Textfield**.

````
validateDOMNesting(...): <li> cannot appear as a child of <select>.
    in li (created by ForwardRef(ButtonBase))
    in ForwardRef(ButtonBase) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(ButtonBase))) ```
````

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue today, and the solution is to remove

```js
SelectProps={{
    native: true,
  }}
```

That fixed it for me.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).